# scrapy / pages with multiple links

Tags: xml, parsing, hyperlink, scrapy

How to crawl multiple profile links in the same page using the base spider. Can anyone help me. I am new to scrapy.

Please help to improve my code

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    rest_page = hxs.select("//h3/a/@href").extract() # this is the link in start url page
    if not not rest_page:
        yield Request(rest_page[0], callback = self.parse)

    titles = hxs.select("//p") # this is the profile page 9 no nextpage links here. need spider to  return to the next link in the landing page when all items are scarped.please help
    items = []

    for titles in titles:
        items ['name']

    items.append(item)
    for item in items:
        yield item
```

Comment: `if not not rest_page` is the same as `if rest_page` :)

Comment: yes both are same pages

Comment: I think you should share a bit more of your spider code. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi paul, I am just learning python and tried scrapy with the following code. The main page( start_url page) has a list of 50 links each page. I need my spider to crawl the 50 links in each page and extract the data in them.Thanks